# mac as a synonym for osx

Tags: discussion, tags

I've suggested [mac](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac) as a synonym for [osx](https://tor.stackexchange.com/tags/osx/synonyms). I can't imagine many cases where the two wouldn't be used for the questions, but does anybody else have thoughts on the matter?

Answer (score 1):

The only situation where a Mac question is not an OSX question is when booting your Mac into Tails. I suppose in that case it would be a Tails question.

Comment: I thought exactly the same.

Comment: So, might it be better then to flip them, and make `osx` a synonym of `mac` instead?

Answer (score 0):

That's a good one. I would even consider adding other synonyms as well, as used in [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tags/osx/synonyms). I would love to +1 it, but don't have privileges. ;(

Answer (score 0):

What about a Hackintosh instances of OS X? I mean intel-based PCs running modified OS X. It sounds weird at first time, but I saw it myself! Will such a synonimization take theese users out?

Comment: Then it would still fall under the `osx` tag.